# SQL literal does not match the string

Tags: sql, database, oracle

At the End of the code I would like to Cast the start_op as DATE. In the raw table the format of Start OP ist DD/MON/YY. When I try to use CAST(start_op AS DATE) I get the ORCALE Error Literal does not match format string.
I read some posts and think that I have to adapt the Start_OP string with a to_date. but I have no Idea how...
Thanks in Advance

```
--CREATE VIEW lhc_format AS
SELECT CAST (Rownr AS number (5)),
CAST (Rd AS VARCHAR2(2)) as rd,
CAST (Ra AS VARCHAR2(2)),
CAST (Cd AS VARCHAR2(2)),
CAST (Ca AS VARCHAR2(2)),
CAST (Al AS VARCHAR2(2)),
CAST (Fnr AS VARCHAR2(7)),
CAST (snr AS NUMBER(2)),
CAST (dep AS VARCHAR2(3)),
CAST (Arr AS VARCHAR2(3)),
CAST (Std AS NUMBER(4)),
CAST (ddc AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (sta AS NUMBER(6)),
CAST (adc AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (Mo AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (Tu AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (We AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (Th AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (Fr AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (Sa AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (So AS NUMBER(1)),
CAST (actyoe AS VARCHAR2(3)),
CAST (actypefullname AS  VARCHAR2(11)),
CAST (ag AS VARCHAR2(1)),
CAST (agfullname AS  VARCHAR2(6)),
CAST (start_op AS DATE)
FROM lhc_raw;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `to_date()`:

```
to_date(start_op, 'DD/MON/RR')
```

Comment: Storing dates as character strings is a design flaw.  Storing dates as a character string with only a 2-digit year compounds the flaw by re-creating the Y2K problem - 21 years after the solution.  Though you do mention "raw table", which _could_ indicate that you are storing the data exactly as it was provided by an outside source.  If that's the case, the usual solution is to move the correctly modified data to a "working" table, rather than just lay a view on it.